# Draw Circle on TouchEvent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, touch-event

I am trying to draw the circle on touch event. In swiftUI, TapGasture is not returning the touch location so i used UIKit touch event to get the touch location. Now in SwiftUi, i tried to draw the circle on touch location as

```
ZStack {
                                    Rectangle()
                                    Image(uiImage: self.shareImage).renderingMode(.original).resizable().padding(5)

                                Circle()
                                    .stroke(lineWidth: 2) 
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue).offset(point.x, point.y)


                                }
```

But Circle is not drawing on the image. How do we set the circle's X and Y position

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `point` is calculated correctly you need to use `.position` instead of `.offset`

```
Circle()
   .stroke(lineWidth: 2) 
   .foregroundColor(.blue)
   .position(point.x, point.y)
```

Comment: Position API is not positioning the circle correctly. It is drawing in wrong place. for example the tap point is top right corner means the circle draws some where in the middle of the view. The tap point is returning correctly but the circle is not drawing on the tapped location

Comment: `position` is a centre of view in parents coordinate system, so if it is not located where expected, then `point` was not calculated properly.